# Multiline Regex in Node.js/Gulp Not Catching

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, gulp

I'm trying to create a regex to match to this below:

```
<!--
I'm a comment.
Here's another line.
-->
```

I **do not** want it to match similar comments like

```
<!--remove
Here's some content.
remove-->
```

Or:

```
<!-- TOC -->
- [Click here](https://example.com)
<!-- /TOC -->
```

I have tried this regex:
`\<!--[^remove][^]*?-->$\gm` and I have tried `\<!--[^remove][\s\S]*?-->$\gm` and they are not working. I'm not sure what else to try.

I am using this inside of a gulp task to replace these comments with an empty string. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the rule for which comments you which not? the `<!--` and `-->` marks forming each single line?

Comment: @JanStránský I'm trying to find a regex to match the format of the first one listed and not the other two. I'm working with converting a library of docs from .md to pdf and different formats for comments are used throughout several files.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the problem, I propose `/^\s*<!--\s*$[^]*^\s*-->\s*$/gm` regex. Explanation:

- `/gm` ... g=global (replaces all occurrences), m=multiline, treat `^` and `$` as beginning/end of line (not only of the input)
- `^` ... beginning of line (in the multiline mode, "normally" only beginning of the input)
- `$` ... end of line (see above)
- `\s` ... space
- `\s*` ... zero or more spaces
- `^\s*<!--\s*$` ... `<!--` is only non-space text on the line (can have some spaces before or after, but no text)
- `[^]*` ... zero or more any character (including new line)
- `^\s*-->\s*$` ... similar to `<!--`

Example:

```js
var str = `
Lorem ipsum
<!--   
I'm a comment.
Here's another line.
-->
Lorem ipsum
<!--remove
Here's some content.
remove-->
Lorem ipsum
<!-- TOC -->
- [Click here](https://example.com)
<!-- /TOC -->
Lorem ipsum
`

console.log(str.replace(/^\s*<!--\s*$[^]*^\s*-->\s*$/gm,""))

/*
Lorem ipsum

Lorem ipsum
<!--remove
Here's some content.
remove-->
Lorem ipsum
<!-- TOC -->
- [Click here](https://example.com)
<!-- /TOC -->
Lorem ipsum
*/
```

Comment: This works great here, and it works on https://www.regexpal.com/, but when I try to use it in my gulpfile.js it does not work. I'm using gulp-markdown-pdf which uses remarkable.js for conversion. I'm wondering if the problem lies there somewhere.